# Kubernetes namespace and resources within created by Helm won't delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm trying to delete a namespace and all the resources within it as well as the helm charts.

I have created a Kubernetes namespace manually and within this namespace I have deployed a Helm chart through the following commands using Tillerless Helm v2:

`$ kubectl create namespace my-namespace`

`$ helm tiller run my-namespace -- helm upgrade --install my-release --namespace=my-namespace ./helm-chart`

I have then tried to delete the namespace through a simple `kubectl delete namespace my-namespace`. The namespace then seems to be recreated with all the resources within it being recreated too.

Before Delete:

```
kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
my-namespace  Active    45m
```

After Delete:

```
kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
my-namespace  Active    5s
```

I've also tried to remove the helm charts individually with the command `helm tiller run my-namespace -- helm delete my-release --purge` but it keeps coming back. Have also tried to delete resources under the namespace using `kubectl -n my-namespace delete daemonsets,replicasets,secrets,services,deployments,pods,rc,serviceAccounts,statefulsets --all` but same result of resources being recreated.

Comment: What is the version of your helm & kubectl?